# objective-c global string

Tags: objective-c, variables, global

I know this has been asked many times, but I cant find answer to my problem.

I want to extract a string variable from another file.

I wrote such:

`NSMutableString *universalString;` in `AppDelegate.m`

I import this string in `MainViewController.m`:

`extern NSMutableString *universalString;`

In

```
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    [tableView1 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    TestViewController *viewCon = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"viewCon" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCon animated:YES];        
    [viewCon release];

`universalString = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}`
```

In `TestViewController.m`, also `extern NSMutableString *universalString;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    UITextView *newtextview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
    newtextview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [newtextview setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];    
    newtextview.text = universalString;

    [self.view addSubview:newtextview];
    [newtextview release];
}
```

I want to extract this `universalString` from MainViewController., but nothing happens until I click twice forth and back through, then this `universalString` appear in `TestViewController.m`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, first off your description of your problem is unintelligible.

Comment: Could you provide more code and try to use the code boxes? This is very hard to read.

Comment: Why not just use a property on your app delegate?

Comment: Guys, I dont deserve minus... Please be patient with me! Minus makes this site uncomfortable to use...

Comment: @georg do you mean i write like this property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *universalString; and then I import it in both ViewControllers? Please explain in more details, as I am interested to know what you do exactly mean.

Comment: @turbo Ok, I will do it soon.

Comment: I am pretty sure I know what you are trying to do, if you clean it up a bit I will try to help. Unfortunately I don't have a mac available to me anymore, so I can't just cut and paste you an example and I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: @turbo I see, I am very obliged for your help. Now I have edited, is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a little bit of code in my email, you should hopefully be able to apply it:

What you have to do is create an app delegate with universalString set up as a property.  Include it in both view controllers, and use the following to set/get it.

```
NamedAppDelegate* navigationDelegate = (NamedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

newtextview.text = navigationDelegate.universalString; //get
navigationDelegate.universalString = "string"; //set
```

Again, I'm a bit rusty(and can't check my own source code because I don't have access anymore), I hope this is enough for you to be able to apply it.